# Circle quadrant and multiple logical operators

Tags: c#, if-statement, switch-statement, operators

I'm trying to do a calculation on a circle with angles and a triangle inside.

Is it possible to group logical operators, or is it not advisable.

EX: If the angle is in quadrant 1 of the circle (>315 deg but 45 deg or less), or in quadrant 3 (> 135 deg but less then <= 225 deg).

My basic code works out to:

```
if (angle > 315 && angle <= 45)
{
    //do codeA
}
else if (angle > 135 && angle <= 225)
{
    //do codeA
}
```

etc.

What I want to do is:

```
if ((angle > 315 && angle <= 45) || (angle > 135 && angle <= 225)
{
    //do codeA
}
else if ((angle > 45 && <= 135) || (angle > 225 && angle <= 315)
{
    //do codeB
}
```

I'm thinking instead of looking at a switch operator, since I have been drastically underusing those.

My two questions are:

1. Regardless of if it is the best way, is it possible to group logical operators the way I want to `(if ((A == 1 && B == 1) || (A == 2 && B == 4))`?
2. Would a switch statement be the proper way to do this?

Comment: Your doing it the correct way.

Comment: ((A == 1 && B == 1)||(A==2 && B==4)) you mean?

Comment: Tested it out and made it work. Answer above is the correct one, which for some odd reason did not work for me a few months ago. I'll blame being newer to programming.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally

1. **1st Quadrant** 0-90
2. **2nd Quadrant** 90-180
3. **3rd Quadrant** 180-270
4. **4th Quadrant** 270-360.

So if **A** is the angle , when you divide it by **180** you get a remainder 0-90 when you are in the first or the third quadrant.

So you can simple use the modulo operator to simplify your condition.

```
if (  (A % 180) < 90 )
{
  //first or third quad
}
else
{
  //second or fourth quad
}
```

Please customize it to your **angle ranges and boundary conditions**

You cannot use a **switch statement** here because you are using an inequality comparison

Comment: Thanks for the answerless answer. . . "Can I do A?" "You can do B." "But can I do A?"

Comment: If you ask **Can I do A** here and A can be simplified people will tell you so...

Comment: The problem is I'm not using the circle quadrant for a circle calculation, I'm finding which side of a triangle to calculate using coh, which requires those angles for me to know which length is adjacent. This is why I wanted A answered and not your B.